# College group project, brainstorming ideas

Tags: android, project

Two parts to this question

1) I am working with a group of six others in a computer science class and will be creating an Android application over the next 3 or 4 months. I am looking for suggestions as to how we can come up with an idea that is not only practical but also possible to complete in the time given. I am the only one in the group that has experience with the SDK but the whole group is proficient in Java.

My main concern is taking on too much and taking too long to decide.

Summary: How should we go about deciding what we want to do?

2) Any one have any ideas? Is there anything anyone would like to see implemented on Android? I find projects like this are way easier to get motivated for when it isn't just for the class so if anyone has any ideas I am all ears.

Comment: Fyi. App Inventor may accelerate how much you can accomplish in a short time.

"To use App Inventor, you do not need to be a developer. This is because instead of writing code, you visually design the way the app looks and use blocks to specify the app's behavior."

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/  
http://www.appinventor.org

Comment: EDIT: The idea behind app inventor is very cool but I am disappointed that I can't actually export the project and do some of it in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about an android app to do distributed brainstorm sessions. Code up a Google App site as a shared info distributing point and collect the ideas. After collection analyze them and add a scoring system.

Should be fun and doable and you can use it for selecting your next project.

Comment: Wow... I really actually like that idea. I am going to give this some thought. Does anyone know of anything like this that already exists?

Comment: http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/07/15/10-collaborative-brainstorming-web-apps-when-you-work-as-a-group.html  Most of them are actually mindmapping tools, but I think they are too fiddly, even on a PC, let alone on a smartphone.

Comment: This is slightly off topic but I really enjoyed collaborating with Google Wave when working with small groups and am very disappointed that it didn't catch on. While Google Wave is probably beyond our small project I can definitely imagine doing a simple, easy to use brainstorming tool.

Comment: Also what do you look for in a brainstorming/collaboration tool? 

I feel like simpler is better especially on a mobile device, any one else have input on this?

Comment: @Tarmon - If you really liked the collaboration aspects of Google Wave and want to work something like that into you project, go for it. Working on a project that is interesting to the team ensures the highest chance at success (all other factors being even).

Answer (score 5):

your best bet is to look around for "pain".  is there something about your school that drives everyone nuts?  can you think of a way to solve it or at least make it a little more bearable in some way?  If you solve peoples problems, they will beat a path to your door.

alternatively, you could take something that everyone loves and make it better.  these kinds of ideas are useful, but i think you get more bang for your buck if you improve a horrible process rather than incremental improving an already good thing.

Comment: This kind of made me laugh, "look for pain!". But really that is a great suggestion.

Comment: it really is a mind set.  once you are in that mode, you will see so many opportunities that other people are completely blind to.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have a lot of motivation and can get the support of your friends if you make something you and your friends will realy want to use.

An interesting app might be one for your university.  Some universities have official apps, but most don't.  This could be interesting because you might be able to integrate your project with resources from the administration (involves talking to other people and working with a foreign interface) or use RSS feeds and XML data from your college's website.  You could add features like weather on campus, course lists, an integrated map of the campus, latest school news, and the like.  It's a manageable project but can be expanded and improved in many sorts of ways.

Comment: I like the fact that you bring up having a smaller manageable project that can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [**Forum**](http://androidforums.com/application-requests/) that people have announced a ton of ideas they thought about. If you find one you like then I would look at the market or at [**AppBrain**](http://www.appbrain.com) to make sure it doesn't exist. I thought an app for **Parental SMS Watch App** would be cool. A parent could flag words that would them alerts when there kids got a message when a word like "sex" comes across. Hope this helps. I have been in the college scene just recently. Good luck with your design project!